# RSpec, implicit subject, and exceptions

Tags: ruby, rspec

Is there a way to properly test exception raising with implicit subjects in rspec?

For example, this fails:

```
describe 'test' do
  subject {raise 'an exception'}
  it {should raise_exception}
end
```

But this passes:

```
describe 'test' do
  it "should raise an exception" do
    lambda{raise 'an exception'}.should raise_exception
  end
end
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`subject` accepts a block which *returns* the subject of the remainder.

What you want is this:

```
describe 'test' do
  subject { lambda { raise 'an exception' } }
  it { should raise_exception }
end
```

Edit: clarification from comment

This:

```
describe 'test' do
   subject { foo }
   it { should blah_blah_blah }
end
```

is more or less equivalent to

```
(foo).should blah_blah_blah
```

Now, consider: without the `lambda`, this becomes:

```
(raise 'an exception').should raise_exception
```

See here that the exception is raised when the subject is evaluated (before `should` is called at all). Whereas with the lambda, it becomes:

```
lambda { raise 'an exception' }.should raise_exception
```

Here, the subject is the lambda, which is evaluated only when the `should` call is evaluated (in a context where the exception will be caught).

While the "subject" is evaluated anew each time, it still has to evaluate to the thing you want to call `should` on.

Comment: I'm wondering why though.  Subject isn't called and stored, but rather called on each test.  Why do I need to wrap it in a lambda at all?

Comment: Because "subject" is a block which produces something on which "should" should be called.  By doing this, you produce the equivalent of:

    (lambda { raise 'an exception' }).should raise_exception

rather than, as yours would, above:

    (raise 'exception').should raise_exception

The subject block will be *evaluated* before `should` is called (and, as it happens, it will raise an exception). You want `should` to be called on the block that raises the exception. Sorry if I'm not being clear.

Comment: Whoops, formatting in comments is less awesome. Updated answer to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer explains the solution pretty well. I just wanted to mention that RSpec has a special helper called `expect`. It's just a little easier to read:

```
# instead of saying:
lambda { raise 'exception' }.should raise_exception

# you can say:
expect { raise 'exception' }.to raise_error

# a few more examples:
expect { ... }.to raise_error
expect { ... }.to raise_error(ErrorClass)
expect { ... }.to raise_error("message")
expect { ... }.to raise_error(ErrorClass, "message")
```

More information can be found in the [RSpec documentation on the built-in matchers](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers).

Comment: Indeed. This helper wasn't present at the time of the original question and answer, but that is probably helpful to people looking for information about this.

Then again, this is not, strictly speaking, an answer to the question.